# How to count distinctly with conditions?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a query something like this, and it gives how many shops we have for each product and cluster.

```
SELECT product,
         cluster,
         count(distinct shop_id) AS shops
FROM a
WHERE site = 1 
GROUP BY  1, 2
```

However, I'd like to see whether there are other shops with the same cluster for each product. So, if there are other shops (> 1) YES, if not (<= 1) NO, and my desired output would be like this:

```
    product | other_shops
    X            Yes
    Y            No
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) I.e. [mcve].

Comment: why is the cluster not part of the result? Should the result table have: product, cluster, other_shops?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct` and `count` with `group by` and the `case` statement to show either `yes` or `no` in a new column. I' ve created a set of sample data to demonstrate that using raw SQL, but I believe that it will be very similar for the Athena console. Try [this link to the live demo](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/74CHxvd) (I am not sure how long it last available).

Sample data and a table with columns `product`, `cluster`, and `shop`.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
 product TEXT,
 cluster TEXT,
 shop TEXT
);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES 
('p1', 'c1', 's1'), ('p1', 'c1', 's2'), ('p1', 'c1', 's3'), 
('p1', 'c2', 's1'), ('p1', 'c2', 's2'), ('p1', 'c2', 's3'), 
('p1', 'c3', 's1'), ('p1', 'c3', 's2'), ('p1', 'c3', 's3'), 
('p2', 'c1', 's1'), ('p2', 'c1', 's2'), ('p2', 'c1', 's3'),
('p2', 'c2', 's1'), ('p2', 'c2', 's2'), ('p2', 'c2', 's3'),
('p2', 'c3', 's1'), 
('p3', 'c1', 's1');
```

The query

```
SELECT DISTINCT cluster, product, count(shop) AS qtd, 
CASE WHEN count(shop) > 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS other_shops
FROM t1 
group by cluster, product;
```

The output will be

```
Cluster|product|shop qtd|other_shops
c1|p1|3|YES
c1|p2|3|YES
c1|p3|1|NO
c2|p1|3|YES
c2|p2|3|YES
c3|p1|3|YES
c3|p2|1|NO
```